# Spring Batch: How can I commit changes to db before the step gets finished?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a step as follow that persists some records in **Table1**:

```
    <step id="myStep" parent="abstractStep"
          next="anotherStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="myReader" writer="myWriter" commit-interval="1"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

In the writer of this step, I write a record in **Table2**, and update another record in **Table3**.
But the problem is that, the new record of Table2 and the updated record of Table3 won't get committed until the step gets finished.

How can I commit these changes to Table2 and Table3, before the step gets completed?

Comment: actually it should commit after each write operation, due to your configuration of commit-interval 1, how do you know it's not committing before step completion?

Comment: If you want to commit Table2 before Table3 ,checking whether its possible to split it into 2 steps.

Comment: No, I can't split it in two steps. Isn't any other way? @Sajith

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  You want the records you wrote for Table2 and Table3 to be persisted even if the transaction to write to Table1 fails and is rolled back?

Comment: @jeff303 Yes, exactly I want this. The reason why I want this is that I want to have a logging system to see that when the step writer started and when it gets finished. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: The Spring Batch job explorer can probably help you query the status of each step from another process.  Refer to this:  http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html-single/index.html#advancedMetaData